# Python 3: object() takes no parameter

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a class inside a file called `Weapons.py` called `Pistol` that looks like this:

```
class Pistol(object):
    MAXAMMO = 6
    def __init__(self, ammo):
        if(ammo <= self.MAXAMMO):
            self.ammo = ammo
    def shoot(self):
        if(ammo > 0):
            accuracy = random.randint(0, 3)
            return 3 * accuracy
            ammo -= 1
        else:
            print("No ammo")
```

And a class called `ColtM1911` that inherits from `Pistol`.  It looks like this:

```
class ColtM1911(Pistol):
    MAXAMMO = 7
    def __init__(self, ammo):
        self.ammo = 7
```

When I run:

```
import Player
import SetUp
from Utils import *
import pickle
import TitleAnimation
import os
import SaveLoad
from Weapons import *

gun = ColtM1911(5)
```

In another file it gives me `"TypeError: object() takes no parameters"`  When trying this in the shell it worked, so I suspect it is to do with having it in a separate file.

The full traceback is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Documents\game.py", line 3, in <module>
    gun = Weapons.ColtM1911(5)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Could you review the indentation, please; it's important in Python. Also, please show a complete example (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - how is `Weapons` imported?

Comment: from Weapons import * I think this should work...

Comment: Although you have several errors, I see no reason in the code you've posted for the error you claim. Again, please provide a minimal example.

Comment: If you're importing as `from Weapons import *`, you only need to do `gun = ColtM1911(5)`

Comment: Given that we don't have access to most of the other `import`s, this question is impossible to answer. Are you *certain* the line `gun = ` is the issue? Can you provide the full traceback? And again, please supply a **minimal example**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, it was a lower case o

Comment: @jonrsharpe even when the other imports are removed the same thing happens

Comment: @Batfink02 so **why have you included them?!**

Comment: @jonrsharpe because you asked for them...? Sorry

Comment: It really is a lot easier to help if you provide the shortest possible complete program that illustrates the problem. The people trying to help out here can't reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @Batfink02 where?! Have you actually read the article I linked to? We need a **minimal example**, so that we can run it and see what happens. If I copy and paste your code into two files, `Weapons.py` and `so.py` (having removed the `import`s I don't have), and run the latter... nothing happens. Also, your traceback **does not match** the code you've posted (although that still **wouldn't explain the error you claim**).

Comment: Note that (apart from the main problem here) base-class constructors are *not* automatically called in Python, so your `ColtM1911` constructor needs to start by calling `Pistol.__init__(self, ammo)`.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff actually, the `ColtM1911.__init__` isn't needed *at all*. You don't *need* to call the base-class initialiser, although it's usually a good idea!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just trying to help. This person seems new to Python and is headed for trouble if they don't know how base-class constructors are supposed to work in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm dorry for wasting your time.  I fixed it below VVV

Answer (score 2):

The **only** way I can recreate your error is if `Pistol` is actually defined as:

```
class Pistol(object()):
                 # ^ note extraneous parentheses
```

In Python 3.x, you don't need `object` at all; all classes are new-style by default. Also, there are logic errors and `M1911.__init__` is redundant. Try something like:

```
import random

class Pistol:

    MAXAMMO = 6

    def __init__(self, ammo):
        if ammo <= self.MAXAMMO:
            self.ammo = ammo
        else:
            # what do you want do do here? Raise an error? Set ammo = MAXAMMO?

    def shoot(self):
        if self.ammo > 0:
            self.ammo -= 1
            return 3 * random.randint(0, 3)
        else:
            print("No ammo")

class ColtM1911(Pistol):

    MAXAMMO = 7
```